# Java Transferir datos entre Formularios

Tags: java, formularios, datos

Hola amigos les cuento que tengo dos formularios. Del primero me abre el segundo con un botón. Pero quiero obtener el texto de 2 JTexfields . He intentado crear variables globales en el 1er formulario para invocarlas desde el formulario secundario pero no logro que esos datos se jales y muestren en el formulario primario pero no lo hace ni tampoco sale error. También he intentado crear atributos privados de la clase formulario primario y definir un constructor con parámetros que sería los dos datos que quiero jalar , en este caso me marca error en el constructor con dos parámetros diciendo que puede ocurrir un SQLException y debe ser capturado o declararse como "throws SQLException" y que debo declararlo en la cabecera del constructor y cuando lo quiero hacer me sale otro mensaje de advertencia diciendo "} expected" a pesar que al constructor no le faltan llaves, y cuando le doy click al símbolo me sugiere:: "create Test Class JUNit in Test Package" . Podrían por favor orientarme. Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, Dante, bienvenido al sitio. Lo del constructor con dos argumentos parece correcto. No entiendo de donde sale esa SQLException ya que no has mencionado nada de base de datos. En cualquier caso es muy dificil ayudarte si no pones nada del código que has intentado.

Comment: Sugerencia != error.

Comment: Ah disculpa amigo, si uno de los formularios trabaja y otra clase trabaja con conexión a Base de datos y es en ese formulario en el que quiero definir un segundo constructor con dos parámetros y ahí es cuando me sale advertencia SQLException ,etc